# replace words in a file

Tags: command-line, command, string

Assume that the word `child` had to be replaced with `son` in a file consisting of sentences (not a list of words).

It isn't a straight string replacement; for example, the following should not happen:

`children` should not be changed to `sonren`

but the following should happen:

`child.` should be changed to `son.`

`child!` should be changed to `son!`

Basically, the text that is to be replaced must be an independent word and the word separators must be preserved.

How can this be done without hard-coding for every possible word separator?

Comment: You need `sed 's/\<child\>/son/g' ` or `sed 's/\bchild\b/son/g'`

Comment: post a testable input sample and expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest There isn't a strict test case. The answer should work for a general notion of what a word is.

Comment: @Yashas, you already got the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) command:

```
sed -i 's/\<child\>/son/' /path/to/your/file
```

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
> edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied). The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links. This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.

---

Considering your example, with the following test file:

```
child
child.
child!
children
```

Run the command and you'll get:

```
son
son.
son!
children
```

---

**EDIT:**
To manage case in which you have more than one time the word `child` on the same line, you have to add `g` in the command:
`sed -i 's/\<child\>/son/g' /path/to/your/file`